# How to get the last's and previous appended div attribute and content onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I add new divs with jQuery `append()`, and I want to be able to get the individual content and attributes of the last div and previous ones `onclick`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#ClickDiv').live("click",function(){

IaNm=prompt("Enter Name","Name here...");
IaLang=prompt("Enter Lang","Lang here...")

$('.box:last').append('<div class="box" lang="'+IaLang+'">'+IaNm+'</div>')
})
$('.box').click(function(){
LstNm=$(this).text()
LstT=$(this).attr('lang')
$('b').html(LstNm+' : '+LstT)

})
})    


</script> 
<input type='button' value='New Div' id='ClickDiv'>
<div class='box' lang='en'>one</div>
<div class='box' lang='fr'>two</div>
<div class='box' lang='de'>three</div>

<b></b>
```

Comment: OP's demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/mZnMe/

Comment: You should use `var` preceding new variables when you want to define them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
```

to

```
$('.box').live( "click", function(){
```

If you want to catch the click event for new elements added after the document load event

EDIT:
change `$('.box:last').append( ... )` to `$('.box:last').after(... )` so the new element will be added after the las elment and not inside of it

Comment: Use `.on` instead of `.live` if you are using jQuery 1.7 as `.live` is deprecated as of 1.7.

Comment: PS: `live()` is great for AJAX apps!

Comment: neither `.on()` or `.live()` is working. when I add a new div and click on it I get something like this **threefour : de** instead of **four : it**

Comment: with `after()` instead of `append()` it's working. thx @Alon --- but only with `.live()`.  `.on()` is working only for the existing divs.